# Multiplying Cell with elements of a matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication, cell-array

I have a 1xm cell array `A{}`, with each element of the array being NxN matrix and a matrix `W(N1,m)`.
I need to calculate

```
Sum(j) = W(j,1)*A{1,1} + W(j,2)*A{1,2}
```

and I am doing the following:

```
for j=1:N1
  sum=false(N);  
  for k=1:m  
    sum = sum + W(j,k)*A{1,k};  
  end  
  Sum(j)=sum  
end
```

Or more visually :
`Matrix W(let's say N1=2)

|W11 W12||A{1,1}| = |W11*A{1,1} + W12*A{1,2}|

|W21 W22||A{1,2}| = |W21*A{1,1} + W22*A{1,2}|`

Is there a way of doing it without using the loops?

Comment: what is `m`? isn't it just `2`? are `N1` and `N` meant to be the same variable? I think you are using `N` to express two different things here

Comment: Not sure I understand the data structure, could you post some code that defines a couple of elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that without for-loops, you can rape (pardon the expression) the [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html) command:

```
w_func = @(j)arrayfun(@(k)(W(j, k) * A{k}), 1:m, 'Un', 0)
sum_func = @(x)sum(cat(3, x{:}), 3)
S = arrayfun(@(j)sum_func(w_func(j)), 1:N1, 'Un', 0);
```

This produces a cell array `S` that contains all the sums, from `S{1}` to `S{N1}`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused over what you are trying to do, but if I understand it correctly, this code should work:

```
temp = cell2mat(A);
a_sum = temp*repmat(eye(n),m,1); % this reduces A by performing sum like operation so [1 1 1 3;0 1 0 2]
                                 % becomes [2 4; 0 3]

Sum = W * a_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also not sure I understood the question, but here is some code to consider:

```
%# create some data resembling what you described
N = 2;
m = 4;
N1 = 5;
W = rand(N1,m);
A = cell(1,m); for i=1:m, A{i} = rand(N); end

%# do the multiplications
s = cell(N1,1);
for j=1:N1
    AA = cellfun(@times, A, num2cell(W(j,:)), 'UniformOutput',false);
    s{j} = sum(cat(3,AA{:}), 3);
end
```

The cell array `s` now contains the result such that:

```
s{j} = W(j,1)*A{1} + W(j,2)*A{2} + ... + W(j,m)*A{m}
```

thus `s` is a cell array of size N1-by-1, where each cell contains an N-by-N matrix

Comment: @EitanT: two-loops really if you count CELLFUN :) I just thought I propose a working solution. That way OP can confirm if it gives the expected output.

Comment: I believe that for-loops are slower than `arrayfun` or `cellfun`, so it's not the same loop. But yea :)

Comment: @EitanT: Ah now I see your solution. Just remember ARRAYFUN, CELLFUNC, etc.. all have hidden loops inside them. Nice one nonetheless

Comment: @EitanT: don't write them off just yet (for-loops), JIT acceleration could surprise you...